# Ebook reader cannot be turned on

Tags: ebook-readers

I just bought a Prestigio PER5664 ebook reader and I tried to turn it on.

[According to the manual](https://usermanual.wiki/Prestigio/PrestigioMultireaderPer5664BcUsersManual793722.1592391907.pdf), the *Power* button should be pressed for a few seconds to turn the reader on.

I pressed the button, then a green LED turned on but the display still shows the name and the properties of the reader, never gets to the start screen (if there is any).

Also, the manual says that I can turn it off by pressing the Power button for a few seconds. I can't tell if it is on (I guess the green LED indicates that it is on), but I can't turn it off.

Strangely, *none of the unboxing videos shows how to turn it on*.

What should I do about this?